# CakePHP: complicated join model

Tags: php, cakephp, join, has-and-belongs-to-many

following scenario:

```
Recipe hasMany RecipeItem
RecipeItem belongsTo Recipe, Ingredient
```

(`Ingredient` could be associated with `hasMany RecipeItem`, but I don't need that relation.)

so basically, a one sided HABTM without the join table, because my joining element (the `RecipeItem`) needs to have an additional attribute: count.

This article: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1650/hasMany-through-The-Join-Model describes how to either create/save all at once or completely separated. What I want is to create the one side (the ingredients) separated and the other side (the recipes) together with the association. When creating a new recipe, you could choose multiple ingredients.

How would you do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Try to figure out it with http://cakeapp.com

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I think you should try to simplify your schema.  It sounds needlessly complicated.  Why do you need a record for both a RecipeItem *and* an Ingredient? They seem like they should be the same thing.

You can create additional fields in the join table so you don't need an extra relationship there.  I think you should be able to just use Recipe HABTM Ingredient and be done.

Also, I tend to have trouble formatting my form data correctly for cake's automagic to work.  For me, it is easier to format the join table records I want to save manually, and then save them explicitly with the join table model (after clearing the existing records).  something like:

```
$toSave = array();
$this->loadModel('RecipesIngredients');
foreach($this->data['Ingredient'] as $ingredient) {
    $toSave[] = array(
        'recipe_id'=>$this->data['Recipe']['id'],
        'ingredient_id'=>$ingredient['id'],
        'count'=>$ingredient['count']
    );
}
$this->RecipesIngredients->deleteAll(array('recipe_id'=>$this->data['Recipe']['id']);
$this->RecipesIngredients->saveAll($toSave);
```

Comment: Adding an extra attribute field to the join table was what I did first (which would have been perfect), but the default form input for HABTM is a multi select, how do I associate the attribute count to each selected item in the multiselect, as they are unordered?